Reanimated conditional element, fadeOut doesn't fade out
I have a simple component that is displayed after an action by the user.  On that action, I want to have the element FadeIn and then after 5 seconds, FadeOut.  The fade in works, however, the fade out is without animation.
const userAction = () => {
    setShowSpeedBump(true);
    // do other processing
    setTimeout(() => setShowSpeedBump(false), 5000); // after 5 seconds toggle state to false
  };

{showSpeedBump && (
        <Animated.View
          entering={FadeIn}
          exiting={FadeOut}
          style={styles}
        >
          <Typography h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            Success!
          </Typography>

        </Animated.View>
      )}

I have tried adding .duration() to the FadeIn but that doesn't change anything.  I also tried adding withCallback on the FadeIn so that when it's completed, it toggles state, but that is not a good solution.
Any ideas why the fade out when showSpeedBump toggles back to false, the animation is not smooth?
